# Best way to create a GridView in ASP.NET MVC .Net5/.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, gridview, .net-5

How we can create a GridView in ASP.NET MVC .Net5/.net core, like we have in ASP.NET web form. There are many third party plugins, written in jQuery available for both server side and client side. It totally depends on the requirements of the specific application if the search is needed at client side or server side.
or What is the best way or the best plugins in 2021/2022 to create a GridView in ASP.NET MVC .Net5 /.net core ?

Answer (score 2):

Grid view with server/client side paging, sorting, filtering for Asp.net MVC can be done in few lines of codes if you use [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) jquery library.

**Basically what you will have to do is:**

- Render a simple Html table in your View (CShtml) with data
- Then on Trigger the Datatable script on page load

**Here are some sample codes:**

In your **CSHtml** file you render a Html table with dynamic rows based on your View Model which is a very common code:

```
<table id="tblList" class="table table-responsive hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>Col 1 Data</td>
                <td>Col 2 Data</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in the **script block** you trigger the Datatable plugin to convert your simple Html table into a functional grid view with client side paging, sorting, filtering:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblList').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "lengthMenu": [50, 75, 100],
            "pageLength": 50
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is a sample output of from the codes above (The column names are different of course):
[image]

Don't forget to include the libraries in your page's header (Layout Page):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions, but my question is about What's the best .NET Core library  to manipulate GridView  like MvcContrib...